# Setting Postgresql variable from result of insert for future use

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a table with a UUID key that is generated on insert. I need to use that key in multiple future inserts and want to store it in a variable.

```
    CREATE TABLE table1 (UUID uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(), blah integer);
    CREATE TABLE table2 (UUID uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(), UUID table1Uuid);
    INSERT INTO TABLE1 (blah) values (1234);
    INSERT INTO TABLE1 (blah) values (6789);
.....
    INSERT INTO TABLE2 (table1Uuid theUuidMadeFromInsert1234);
```

I think I can make sure all the future inserts into TABLE2 are in the same session (maybe the same script) as those for TABLE1. Would like to do something like

```
uuid1234 = INSERT INTO TABLE1 (blah) values (1234);
uuid6789 = INSERT INTO TABLE1 (blah) values (6789);
.....
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (table1Uuid uuid1234);
```

but I can't get any syntax to work. I tried

```
create or replace function insertTable1 (junk integer)
    RETURNS UUID
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
declare 
myUuid UUID;
BEGIN
    insert into table1 (blah) values (junk) returning uuid into myUuid;
    return myUuid;
END
$func$;
```

then doing something like `set my.var.uuid = select insertTable1(1234)` and `insert into table2 (table1Uuid my.var.uuid)` with various uses of `current_setting`
I have read many posts on SO, but can't find one that allows the value of the variable to outlast the function and be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
with t1 as (
    insert into table1 (blah) values (1234), (6789)
    returning *
)
insert into table2 (table1Uuid)
select uuid from t1 where blah = 1234;
```

The CTE inserts several rows in `table1`, then the outer query inserts in `table2` the `uuid` that was generated for `blah` `1234`.

Note that if you insert `1234` more than once in the CTE, the outer query will create as many rows in `table2`.

Alernatively, you can isolate the first insert in another CTE:

```
with 
    t1 as (insert into table1 (blah) values (1234) returning *),
    t2 as (insert into table1 (blah) values (456), (789))
insert into table2 (table1Uuid) select uuid from t1
```

Comment: I can't guarantee the blah value will be unique so I need the uuid specific to that particular insert (there are other columns I didn't put in the sample code).

Comment: Does this mean that all the inserts to table2 would have to be in 1 statement? I'll likely have about 20 inserts into table1 and then a hundred into table2. Seems like 1 statement  `with` would become unweildy.